# Camscanner-like app for Mac OSX

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I have some photos of notes that have been sent to me, and I would like to "fix" them in order to have a scanned-like pdf like the one that I get when scanning with Camscanner app (on Android or iOS).
I've done some research but I've found only a discontinued app, `doxcan`.

 Is there a maintained app to do so?

 EDIT: from the comments, here's a more detailed explanation of what I need: 
I need something that allows me to "flatten" the photo and make it in white and black. Just like when in Camscanner you fix the corners of the document and it warps the image in order to make it as it was acquired from scanner. Then it performs a conversion from color to b/w (probably applying some filters too, but nevermind of that) doxcan does it but I cannot find anywhere to download, since it's discontinued... 
[here](http://alternativeto.net/software/doxcan/) is all I found about doxcan

Comment: This doesn't answer  your question, but may be a workaround. Until you can find a replacement for doxcan, maybe you can send the files to your phone and use Camscanner.

Comment: the purpose of this question was exactly to avoid it lol

Comment: I think AlternativeTo is probably going to be better at answering your question

Comment: Last time I checked, alternativeTo suggests only doxcan

Comment: Adobe Acrobat DC does the job.  https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/scan-paper-documents-searchable-pdf.html?set=acrobat--fundamentals--create-pdf

Answer (score 1):

I use PDF Pen Pro to fix up scans and OCR them (optionally) and see as PDF. Depending on what "fix" them up is, the preview app might be fully capable for your needs.

[PDF Expert](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pdf-expert-edit-annotate-and-sign-pdfs/id1055273043?mt=12) also gets great reviews, but I've not needed anything as Preview and PDF Pen Pro have my needs covered.

- https://smilesoftware.com/PDFpen
- https://smilesoftware.com/PDFpenPro

Comment: Yeah, check out Preview first before buying anything, It may do everything you need.

Comment: Right on @dwightk - The PDF Pen trial is also nice to be sure you need it or it does what you think it does.

Comment: Nope, that's not what I need. I need something that allows me to "flatten" the photo and make it in white and black. Just like when in Camscanner you fix the corners of the document and it warps the image in order to make it as it was acquired from scanner. Then it performs a conversion from color to b/w (probably applying some filters too, but nevermind of that) doxcan does it but I cannot find anywhere to download, since it's discontinued...

Comment: @magicleon - Looks like you figured out the edit to the question - if not, see here. [How should I ask about getting a software recommendation?](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2180/how-should-i-ask-about-getting-a-software-recommendation?)